# Is there a way to enable Unity Catalog programatically?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I'm having some trouble trying to figure out how to enable Unity catalog programmatically when rolling out new Azure Databricks instances. In the past we've done this by hand but it would be nice to eliminate these manual tasks.

I've searched the web and read through the Databricks API documentation (https://api-docs.databricks.com/rest/latest/unity-catalog-api-specification.html). I might be using the wrong search terms because I seem to be the only one after this information :'D

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Metastore Assign API](https://docs.databricks.com/api-explorer/workspace/metastores/assign) for that - you can find it in the Databricks API explorer.  It's also available as a [Databricks Terraform resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/metastore_assignment) - `databricks_metastore_assignment`.

Please note that right now this a workspace API, so you need to have a workspace before doing assignment.